# При overflow: hidden появляется горизонтальное пространство

Tags: html, css

Есть следующая структура

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px #888 solid;
  background-color: forestgreen;
  font-size: 60px;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #EFA;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<span class="container">
  <span class="content">
    Text
  </span>
</span>
```

Мне непонятно, почему появляется пустое пространство внутри контейнера внизу, т.е. высота внешнего блока получается большей, чем нужно. Если же для внутреннего блока не указывать `overflow: hidden;` то высота внешнего блока становится меньше, и пустое горизонтальное пространство исчезает.

Можно ли при `overflow: hidden;` Добиться того, чтобы пустого пространства не было?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В контенте убрали `inline` и больше не появляется пустого пространства

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px #888 solid;
  background-color: forestgreen;
  font-size: 60px;
}
.content {
  display: block; //Здесь убрали inline
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #EFA;  
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<span class="container">
  <span class="content">
    Text
  </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px #888 solid;
  background-color: forestgreen;
  font-size: 60px;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #EFA;
  line-height: 2em;
  vertical-align: top; /* !!!!!!!! */
}
```

```html
<span class="container">
  <span class="content">
    Text
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает, но дальнейшее исследованные показало одну странную особенность. См. ниже.